# Can I access a table cell's value that is below the cell I have selected?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a 5X5 table with html and each cell gets a value after clicking on it. If for example I have selected a cell in 3rd row and second column, I want to get the value of the cell in the fourth row and second column.

There is the table :

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is the script to change the content of a cell when it's clicked.

```
$('td').click(function() {
            $(this).html('X');
            $(this).toggleClass('X');        
            $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

I have also tried something like this but it is not effective.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            for (var j = 1; i <= 5; j++) {

                var test1 = $("table tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td:nth-child(" + j + ")").html();
                var k = i+1;
                var test2 = $("table tr:nth-child(" + k + ") td:nth-child(" + j + ")").html();

}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something on your own to solve the problem? Please show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is just to access the next cell's value, not to generate the value in any cell. The first **if($next=='')** essentially checks to see if the selected cell  is the last in the row. If so, it skips down to the next row and starts at the first cell. The second **if($next=='')** checks to see if there are no more cells in the table.

```
$('#table td').click(function(){
    var $next=$(this).next().text();
    if($next==''){
        $next=$(this).parent().next().find('td:first-child').text();
    }
    if($next==''){$next='No more data to display.';}
    alert($next);
});
```

[See Example](https://jsfiddle.net/karljuhlke/5ez1wuxn/)

**EDIT**

After re-reading the question, I altered the jsFiddle to grab the next vertical cell value, as I believe you're asking for. In case the user selects the last value in that column, the value is taken from the first cell in the next column.

```
$('#table td').click(function(){
        //  Grabs the next horizontal value
    var $next=$(this).next().text();
    if($next==''){
        $next=$(this).parent().next().find('td:first-child').text();
    }
    if($next==''){$next='No more data to display.';}
    alert('Next Horizontal Value: '+$next);

    //  Grabs the next vertical value
    var $ind=$(this).index();
    $next=$(this).parent().next().find('td:eq('+$ind+')').text();
    if($next==''){
        $ind++;
        $next=$(this).parent().parent().find('tr:first-child').find('td:eq('+$ind+')').text();
    }
    if($next==''){$next='No more data to display.';}
    alert('Next Vertical Value: '+$next);
});
```

[See Example](https://jsfiddle.net/karljuhlke/5ez1wuxn/)

Comment: I was actually looking for this. Getting the next verticall value. It is really helpfull , thank you a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a solution with a few lines of code, you can test it here  https://jsfiddle.net/cw237zyb/

```
$("td").click(function(){   
   $($(this)[0]).children().attr('style','display:block');
   $($($('.row1')[0]).children()[1]).children().attr('style','display:block');
})
```

in the script you can insert the logic to display the next value,
I hope this is useful